# Using webpack to replace a button in a HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I am a new to webpack, and have a problem.

### my project catalogue is the following:

```
--webpack/
    --components/
       --button/
          -button.css
          -button.js
          -button.html
    --entry.js
    --entry.html
    --dist/
       --js/
       --css/
       index.html
```

I want to compile button/ into entry.html, then entry.html generates index.html by string replace .output catalogue is dist/ .

entry.html like this :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{button}}
</body> 
</html>
```

As you can see, I want to use webpack to replace {{button}} by the button.html;
I don't know How to write webpack.config.js. Can anybody help me out?
 big thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack is not meant to do that kind of task.

What you want is probably a templating engine, like [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/), with an appropriate loader, [handlebars-loader](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader).
Then you can configure your loader to process the template files the way you want.

Comment: Thanks your for your help ! I just want to study how to use component to code web application . so , I don't want to use framework like react. Then I think , i can use template to chain  components .  It's this way rigth ?

Comment: What template engines do is *compile* a template into plain html. This means that if you are generating **static content**, then a template engine like jade, handlebars, ejs or whatever is definitely the **best choice**.  
On the other hand if your site requires dynamicity, a framework like react, angular, backbone or similars could be a better choice.  
In short: *you can but depends on what you're building*